# Change Vue build dist file prefixes

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vue-cli

I'm using vue-cli 3's build command to build my Vue app.

```
 vue-cli-service build
```

Builds me a great set of deployment files. These are prefixed `app.` and `vendor.` etc.

[image]

Is there any way to add some sought of application specific prefix or suffix to these files, such as:

```
signup.app.62948721.js
signup.vendor.3fc5b322.js
...
```

I deploy multiple Vue apps into the same directory structure and I'm wanting a way to differentiate them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create `vue.config.js` in your project and tweak config

```
module.exports = {
    configureWebpack: config => {
        config.output.filename = 'ittus.[name].js';

    },
    chainWebpack: config => {
      config.plugin('extract-css')
          .tap(([options, ...args]) => [
              Object.assign({}, options, { filename: 'css/ittus.[name].css' }),
              ...args
          ])
    }
}
```

Here `ittus` is my prefix

[image]

For more information, you can check vue-cli webpack document https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/dev/docs/webpack.md